# Scripts folder installs empty python 3.10.3

Tags: python

So im pretty new to python and i need pip for something i wanna do, but everytime i install python the Scripts folder where pip should be always installs empty. I make sure that install pip is checked when downloading python. How do I get it to install pip with python?

Comment: Huh?  "please help" is not a question.  Even if it was, you've provided no useful information.  Your "question" is in fact pure gibberish.  You need to put significantly more effort into describing what you're trying to do and what is going wrong.  Please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i edited it to be clearer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Python, it came bundled with pip.

The default packages:

```
C:\Users\<Your username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages
```

A better practice is to install a `venv` for every project you are working on. Every venv will have its own set of dependencies(i.e. packages), and it will be easier to manage them.

You can find installed packages in your venv:

YOUR_PROJECT_PATH\venv\Lib\site-packages

**EDIT**

From official docs:

> Pip not installed¶ It is possible that pip does not get installed by default. One potential fix is:
>
> python -m ensurepip --default-pip

There are also additional resources
for [Installing pip](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel)

Comment: pip doesnt download with python, and ive tried downloading it manually but that doesn't work either. The scripts folder is empty

Comment: Have you tried 'pip --version' or 'python -m pip --version' in cmd?

Comment: yes, it gives me and error, and pip isnt in the scripts folder when python is installed

ive tried these two commands:
$ curl -sSL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py

after running them i get a huge error

Comment: Where did you download Python?) Just install it from official website. Check the checkboxes, and click on Install Now (not Customize installation).

Comment: I did all of that, i checked all the boxes i need to check and it still wont work

Comment: What errors are you getting? Provide more info/screenshots/stacktraces.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/15a39bd9968a6fe798ff9a56dd064122.png

https://gyazo.com/a2f10d2fac4d828ceed51095180561ed.png

https://gyazo.com/ca96ee1dd6f4f25e1c0cb1f9e18e0300.png

Comment: Updated response. Please read that.

Comment: it gave me another error

https://i.gyazo.com/fdbf7ff1079e4c441be7f9988968e79f.png

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: The newest one: 3.10.3

Comment: Uninstall it. And install 3.10.1 (I am using this one). Again check the checkboxes, and  click on Install Now (not Customize installation).

Comment: it didnt install pip

Comment: Now you try py -m ensurepip --default-pip. With the 3.10.1 version of python.

Comment: it still didnt work

Comment: What about python get-pip.py? After downloading get-pip.py

Comment: it throws an error at me every time i run the command

Comment: Okay, try to downgrade again. 3.9 or even earlier (3.8, 3.7). And try it all again. If still does't work, try to uninstall python and reinstall it in different partition other than the C

Comment: still doesnt work, its fine if yall wanna go, im gonna try to fix it on my own